# System threading Timer vs Scheduler

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, scheduled-tasks

I am using Microsoft Graph to get notifications for new emails, and I have to subscribe to the webhook, challenge is the subscription lasts for only 3 days so I have to constantly renew the subscription.
What is the best way to do it? Right now I can see two choices to use a timer or an scheduler, timer looks like and overhead to the application and not that much reliable.
I have not used Timers in any production applications yet, so I am not very much sure about them.

Comment: What kind of application? If it is web where is it hosted?

Comment: @weichch It is a web application, angular + .net core, sql server.
It's hosted on IIS

Comment: Are you hosting it on your own server or taking advantage of a PaaS solution like Azure web apps?

Comment: @baywet own server

Answer (score 0):

Web applications that are inactive in IIS can be flushed by the server. That means that a system threading started from the main web thread would not guarantee you that it runs at the right time or at all if your application does not have a lot of activity. A timer job would guarantee that the job runs on time as long as the machine is online and in an healthy state

Comment: So, according to you a scheduler would be a better choice?

Comment: It's the only one of the two choices that guarantees the subscription renewal will execute at the required time.

Comment: Are there other options considering the configurations I am using?

Comment: You could also implement your own Windows service. Either just for subscription renewal or as a complete standalone dot net core application (Kestrel) with a "hosted service" configured.